# Java- attempting to assign weaker class privileges

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am learning Java (complete) beginner and am getting the below error from my code. I spent some time trying to figure it out myself, but haven't had much luck.

**error: Brightness(int) in FlatScreen cannot implement Brightness(int) in electronics
    void Brightness (int newBrightness) {
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public**

```
public class NewTV {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        FlatScreen fS = new FlatScreen();

        fS.Power("On");
        fS.Brightness(10);
    }



}
interface electronics {

    void Power(String newPower);

    void Brightness(int newBrightness);
}

class FlatScreen implements electronics {

    String Power;
    int Brightness;

    void Power (String newPower) {

        Power = newPower;
        System.out.println("Power: " + Power);
    }

    void Brightness (int newBrightness) {
        Brightness = newBrightness;
        System.out.println("Brightness: " + newBrightness);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Interface methods are all public, even if the `public` keyword is not present. Classes that implement the interface must make all their implemented methods public, and the `public` keyword must be present.

Answer (score 1):

Methods in an interface are `public` by default. However, methods in a *class* are what's called `package-private` by default. Since this is more restrictive than the `public` modifier which is available in the interface, you are prevented from doing this. Instead you must explicitly use the `public` access modifier when implementing the method.

This applies to all situations where you extend or implement a base class; all overridden methods must be at least as visible as the method you're overriding. You're free to make a method *more* widely visible, but not *less*.

For an example of why you can't do this, consider this code:

```
electronics e = new FlatScreen();
e.Brightness(5); // the interface says I can call this, but the implementation says I can't!
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
public void Power (String newPower) {
    Power = newPower;
    System.out.println("Power: " + Power);
}
public void Brightness (int newBrightness) {
    Brightness = newBrightness;
    System.out.println("Brightness: " + newBrightness);
}
```

Methods in `interfaces` are `public` by default. To `override` a `public` method you need to have `public` modifier.

You need to learn about presidency of `access modifiers` in `Java`. If you want to `override` some method you need modifier with higher presidency.